# R.java class in Android

Tags: java, android, xml, class, compilation

I have one serious problem. I was watching some tutorials on YouTube about android programming and after one problems with R.java class appeared. After compiling my project R.java class gets deleted. This problem started when I try to add some sounds, but then I have deleted them, strange is that that I never used them in any .xml or other class or file.

And yes, I tried to clean my project like 1000 times...

In worst scenario I could rewrite everything, but I would love to know how to solve it.

Here is what it looks like http://postimg.org/image/l7iyf1gwr/

Comment: When I had the same exact issue, restarting Eclipse -> Clean all Projects worked for me.

Answer (score 2):

R.java is cleaned when you start a build. You have an error in one of your XML files, and that is why no new version is generated. Or, it seems rather eclipse thinks it's an XML file. Look at the eror messages: all your MP3s are treated as XML files. Try moving these to the raw folder.

Comment: Thank you, this was the problem, somehow I have placed all of those MP3s to my MENU folder insted of raw...

Answer (score 0):

Check the names of all your mp3 files, drawables & xml files. Ensure that they only contains lower case letters, numbers and underscore. Any blank spaces in their names should also be removed. The naming convention should be followed even if you don't use the badly named file anywhere in your code, otherwise the R.java problem would occur.

If it does not solve your problem, check the code inside your xml files for any error. Clean & build the project.